# How to show loading progress when down load multiple image in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, httprequest

I am working magazine based application I have completed online version and now I need to convert my application to offline. For offline version need to download books and need to store all the books inside the document directory retrieve and read the book even if the user is not available in online. Now the problem is all my books are in the form of images if the book contain 100 pages then I need to download 100 images and saved all the images in a particular folder and I need to allow the user to down load more than one book at a time. I need to implement the layout as bellow

[image: Layout design]

Please suggest me some ideas to implement this issues

Comment: Try this https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: AsyncImageview just help us to load the image i need to download and store the image in particular folder

Comment: You are able to store images in - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection 
{
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    
    ///Cache your image
    
    [data release], data = nil;
 [connection release], connection = nil;
    
    [self hiderSpinner];
   
    
}

Answer (score 2):

Use  HJCache. It has features to set maximum number of images to be saved in app directory, duration to download the image of same URL again and memory cache size to load images .

Here is a link :
https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache

And for your info, do not save the files in document directory as it is not recommended for newsstand app.save in cache directory.